# Display Yandex map in Windows Phone 8.1 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, yandex-maps

I need to show yandex map in may WP8.1 application. Yandex map SDK for windows phone is obsolette. How to display Yandex Map on Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632728.aspx) article explains how to set custom tile source to MapControl

In short:

```
MyMap.Style = MapStyle.None;
HttpMapTileDataSource dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource("http://vec02.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.2.3&x={x}&y={y}&z={zoomlevel}");
MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
tileSource.Layer = MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement;
MyMap.TileSources.Add(tileSource);
```